# Push Two View Controller at same time

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I have two buttons in one view controller, they all push one view controller, the problem is when i click two buttons at the same time, the app will crash and give me the error:

> nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
>   2014-02-20 15:11:35.540 TestPush[1147:60b] Finishing up a navigation
>   transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might
>   get corrupted.

how should i push one view controller after another.

Comment: I don't get the purpose of this? Why not just push directly to the secondViewController if you already know you want skip the first. If you need to load both, then push to the firstViewController and on ViewDidAppear in firstViewController push to secondViewController?

Comment: the user may click multiple buttons, i can't control that, and i think it's a good user experience to push the relative view controllers than just the first or the last button's view controller.

Comment: So you actually wants to cancel the first click? It sounds to me like you're making something that might hung up the app in some "waiting time" and takes some time before the app pushes to the firstViewController? Am I right?

Comment: don't allow users to abuse/misuse app. push controller for first button tapped. If user didn't want that controller, he would tap back button and then select the right controller.

Answer (score 2):

Try again by adding this line in both buttons' `IBAction` methods:

```
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

and in `viewWillAppear` of same class add this:

```
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

It will block user interaction as any buttons get tapped.

Comment: but i have seen an app, it pushes one view controller,then after it's finished, it push the second view controller automatically, do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can call both at once but set animated to `NO` for the first push.
OR call the second push in `ViewDidLoad` of the first view controller.

Comment: Chicken is right. that's the way to achieve that. i have used both ways in many apps

Comment: when the first view controller's viewDidLoad is called, how do i know i should push a second view Controller, i don't know how many buttons the user has clicked.

Comment: you should push one controller at a time.. what is the logic behind pushing multiple controllers if user taps multiple buttons at the same time??

Answer (score 1):

If you pushed viewController is not same with current viewController class, add following code before do push:

```
if(![self.navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
      return;
}
```